# List Operation, Converting alphanumeric data while skipping over other data in a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, alphanumeric, string-conversion

thanks for any help you can provide. If there is another post/video/article related to this question, I'll be glad to check that out.

Language: Python

My question: What would be the proper way to construct the code below to skip over the "N/A" and the "Dec 25 2019" in the list  = num.

I found the answer on how to convert the alphanumeric values like "1.19T" into floats, but I can't figure out how to skip over the dates and the "N/A" in the list.  Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

```
num = ["11.1", "1.19T", "22.14", "2.09B", "4.57%", "12.92", "N/A", "Dec 25 2019"]
units = {"M": 1_000, "B": 1_000_000, "T": 1_000_000_000, "": 1, "%": .01}
result = []
for n in num:
        try:
            result.append(float(n))
        except ValueError:
            unit = n[-1]
            n = float(n[:-1])
            result.append(n * units[unit])

print(result)
```

Comment: Where is this data coming from? It's probably a much better idea to use `None` rather than a magic string. Can you provide some more context/information for this?

Comment: It would be wise to split data into homogenous parts instead of mixing different data formats. But if you insist on storing all of the strings into a single list ( or if they are mixed at input ), then regex seem like your only choice. Danger here is that dates themself have many different formats

Comment: You could add another `try/except` within the outer `except` clause itself so it will just `continue` if it fails to convert it the 2nd time.

Comment: AMC, the data was coming from Yahoo Finance, https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BA/key-statistics?p=BA.  I'm just trying to understand web scraping with Python better by scraping the information from "Valuation Measures" and "Financial Highlights" .

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you're trying to separate unit handling from invalid values, as now they're served by the same try/except statement. One (but not the only one) solution is to explicitly handle units:

```
for n in num: 
    try: 
        if n[-1] in units: 
            n = float(n[:-1]) * units[n[-1]] 
        else: 
            n = float(n) 
    except ValueError: 
        continue 
    result.append(n)
```

Another approach, as suggested in the comments, is to use nested try/except block. However, "explicit is better than implicit", so I prefer the one above.

Answer (score 0):

Using `re`:

First I had to remove empty string key from your `units`:

```py
units = {"M": 1_000, "B": 1_000_000, "T": 1_000_000_000, "%": .01}
```

Then I iterate through all your elements, and all saved units to modify all literals to proper arithmetic operation:

```py
>>> num_formatted=[]
>>> for el in num:
...     x=el
...     for k in units:
...         x=re.sub(r"([0-9\.]+)"+k, r"(\1 * "+str(units[k])+")", x)
...     num_formatted.append(x)
...
>>> print(num_formatted)
['11.1', '(1.19 * 1000000000)', '22.14', '(2.09 * 1000000)', '(4.57 * 0.01)', '12.92', 'N/A', 'Dec 25 2019']
```

Thanks to this approach you can have more than one unit per literal, and everything should be computed arithmetically correct.

Once this is done - we can just `eval` all the formatted operations:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> num_formatted_final=[]
>>> for el in num_formatted:
...     try:
...         num_formatted_final.append(eval(el))
...     except:
...         num_formatted_final.append(np.nan) #You can put None instead - I suppose np.nan is more logical choice here
...
>>> num_formatted_final
[11.1, 1190000000.0, 22.14, 2089999.9999999998, 0.045700000000000005, 12.92, nan, nan]
```